# How to get the original attribute name before it was normalized/denormalize an attribute name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I want to create a directive that I can use on `<select>` elements, to tell it to populate the `<select>` with a globally known list that's dynamically updated and shared among all the components in the app.

I envision using it like so:

```
<select ng-model="listentry" select-the-list></select>
```

Here's how I'm going about it so far:

```
.directive('selectTheList', function ($compile, ListData) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1000,
        terminal: true,
        link: function (scope, el, attributes) {
            var child = scope.$new();
            child.listData = ListData.theList;
            el.attr('ng-options', 'listItem.name for listItem in listData track by listItem.id');
            el.removeAttr('select-the-list'); /**** ATTENTION ****/
            $compile(el)(child);
        }
    };
});
```

That is, I assign an `ng-options` attribute that does what I want, based on the scope that I set up for this purpose, and then `$compile` it.

---

This works great. But note the line I commented with **ATTENTION**: This assumes that the user used `<select select-the-list>`, which then got normalized to `selectTheList` and used this directive. However, according to [the directive docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Angular **normalizes** an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) **normalized** name (e.g. `ngModel`). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using [dash-delimited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Computers) attributes on DOM elements (e.g. `ng-model`).
>
> The normalization process is as follows: [... snip ...]
>
> For example, the following forms are all equivalent and match the `ngBind` directive:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  Hello <input ng-model='name'> <hr/>
  <span ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span ng:bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span ng_bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span data-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span x-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
</div>
```

That is, if a user does `<select select:the:list>`, then the directive will be applied, `element.removeAttr('select-the-list')` will not work, and **I'll get an infinite loop**.

---

This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is why I provided all this context. But if this is a good way to do it - what's the best way to find the actual attribute on the element that caused my directive to be called, so I can remove it before re-compiling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creators of angular did indeed envision the need for this. The `attributes` passed into your `link` function is not just a map, but an instance of [`$compile.directive.Attributes`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes). It contains an `$attr` property:

> ## Properties
>
> ### $attr
>
> A map of DOM element attribute names to the normalized name. This is needed to do reverse lookup from normalized name back to actual name.

Thus, your **ATTENTION** line should be:

```
el.removeAttr(attributes.$attr['selectTheList']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is XY problem indeed, because the subject is avoiding recursive compilation.

There are some tricks to handle this.

One of them is to make use of the fact that the only place where DDO object is available as `this` is `compile`:

```
...
compile: function (element, attrs)  {
  attrs.$set(this.name, null);
  // so the appearance of 'compile' won't require nesting link fn
  return this.link;
},
link: ...
```

And changing directive's name or pasting its code won't cause inconsistencies.

Another one is more generic and is particularly useful if removing an attribute isn't applicable for some reason or the directive isn't an attribute:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    ...
    if (element.data('$recursion')) {
        element.data('$recursion', false);
    } else {
        element.data('$recursion', true);
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
}
```